# Overriding a builtin excel function with macro or add in

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

Is it possible to override a builtin excel function with a custom one from a VBA macro or from an add-in? E.g. I would like to override the SUM function and perform own stuff there (SUM is only an example here).

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: No.

Comment: if you're changing what the function itself does, can you really still call that function a sum? It's not just doing a sum anymore. It's a sum + whatever other stuff you want to add to it.

Comment: You can't name functions after the older XLM commands, e.g. SORT, either...

Answer (score 4):

This might be a simple question but the answer is something that every vba (excel) programmer should know well :

**There is a hierarcy which is followed when there is function name clash.**

Here is the structure with priority :

1. 1st Priority given to default excel functions (e.g. Sum, Count, ...)
2. 2nd Priority given to reference dll functions. (*more later*...)
3. 3rd Priority given to add-in functions (e.g Days360 - in case of excel 2003)
4. 4th Priority given to Module functions or custom UDF that you create.

Also remember, in 2nd priority case :
If two or more references have same function name (e.g if we reference ADO library & DAO library together there might be some name clash), then priority can be manually set by you as per requirement. In Excel VBA IDE go to Tools >> References >> Select any library and on the right hand side of the Window click on Priority UP / Down to increase or decrease priority of the function library.

Hope this helps all :)